# How to stop too many redirects in springboot - react - google auth bundled app - securityconfig

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am stuck with too many redirects problem

The initial example code I used is

https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/tree/master

The example app runs ok if spring and react are run separately.

But I bundled react inside Spring boot and used maven plugins ( front end plugin + proxy) , the bundled jar is giving the below error -

***Basically too many redirects or filter chain  ***

Configuration:

**application.properties**

> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=4..........com
> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=qsl,....Af
> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri={baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile

**React constants**

```
export const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
export const ACCESS_TOKEN = "accessToken";

export const OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

export const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + "/oauth2/authorization/google?redirect_uri=" + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
```

**Google side config:**

[image]

**I hope I have given enough info. Can I ask if it is possible to help me solve the issue?**

**EDIT:**
It seems the problem is with security configuration

**How to change the old security class to the new model SecurityConfig ?**

This is the new spring security model (avoiding websecurityadapter)

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

     @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/sign-in")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/sign-in");
    return http.build();
}
```

Old spring model security configuration

```
import com.grodutch.shop.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.oauth2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.grodutch.shop.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

[image]

See 5.1 Custom Login page

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

It seems there is a ping pong between spring and react ?

Comment: I would debug your `onAuthenticationSuccess` method and make sure you are not redirecting it to itself (check the value of the `targetUrl` and your `determineTargetUrl` method)

Comment: @KrisSwat, it is better to add urls which cause the loop (press F12 in browser -> Network tab -> you will see a lot of redirects with the same 2-3 urls). As the loop can be during login or during social signup or when you just trying to access home page and the reason will be different.

Comment: @SveKamenska added too many redirect network activity

Comment: I think, it is better to start from the begiining and break down the issues. As currently you moved from the original request (combined react + spring = too many redirects) and face other security issues. 
Plus it is very hard to help as you mentioned different security configs in screenshot (login form is specified) and in text (login form is commented out + unknown endpoints_whitelist const). Also what is the code for /sign-in controller?

Comment: Basically, what happens is 1. You are trying to reach home page. 2. Security is configured that home page is secured. So redirect to /sign-in occurs. 3. Either in react router or in spring controller responsible for /sign-in redirection occurs to also /sign-in. For example, /sign-in is not in spring security permitted list, so spring automatically redirects to login page (which is this case the same page - /sign-in) - that causes too many redirects

Comment: This explanation logic makes sense. I want to whitelist or make some urls like permit all. But do not know how to in spring boot 3. the spring controller has /login endpoint (see github code AuthController). Not sure if I have to change /login to /sign-in etc

Comment: The original example and my idea are a little different i.e. the OOTB example has login button, but I directly land on sign-in page if not authenticated. I am now locked with redirect loop issue only. Sorry for too many edits on the question, but that's the nature of the problem :)

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer. on another note, when I tested the OOTB example, I did see that it requires two attempts to login - https://youtu.be/JsLI9B7Qxtw   .  Appreciate if anyone answers the flow of calls between react - spring - oauth